# Ubuntu not booting in GUI

Tags: boot

I'm running Ubuntu 22.10, Whenever I start the computer it's not booting into the GUI but at white text being printed to the screen and a blinking cursor, Part of the text says,

snd_hda_intel 0000:00.1f.3: Too manyBDL entries: buffer=2097152, period=65536

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Is this a fresh installation of 22.10 or have you been using the version for a while?

Comment: I have been using it for quite some time